# How to link the map view without map activity in android?

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps

In my application, I am using two layouts in main layout using include function. In those two layouts, one layout is a map view. Is it possible to link that map view with main activity without MapActivity.

Comment: It depended by design "Google" there is now way to separate them.

Comment: @IamStalker not possible to use it in activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depended by design "`Google`" there is now way to separate them
You can check it here

[Using Android MapView without the MapActivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488516/using-android-mapview-without-the-mapactivity)

Comment: No problem m8 enjoy programming on android. :)